# add new SRID to sql server

Tags: sql-server, srid

Is it possible to add a new SRID to sql server 2012?

I've tried

```
insert into sys.spatial_reference_systems values (4938, 'GEOCCS["GDA94",DATUM["Geocentric Datum of Australia 1994",SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137.0,298.257222101,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],TOWGS84[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6283"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["m",1.0],AXIS["Geocentric X",OTHER],AXIS["Geocentric Y",EAST],AXIS["Geocentric Z",NORTH],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4938"]]', 'metre', 1)
```

But I get

> Ad hoc updates to system catalogs are not allowed.

Haven't had much luck on google with any answers as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not an answer per se:

a SRID in MS SQL server is almost useless because it doesn't support transformations. Also I think you can use SRID which isn't in spatial_reference_systems table for geometry.
see :
[Thread about it](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlspatial/thread/4e3b8a82-64e4-4f21-b96c-319e5eccd0e9)