# How can I create geometry in SQL2012 with custom SRID?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-spatial

I want to create geometry using EPSG 2039 in mssql 2012.
This srid doesn't exist in sys.spatial_reference_systems

any idea how I can do it ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add new line to spatial_reference_system table (this is how you do it in posgresql, but should work in mysql too )

Comment: I'm talking about MSSQL - And I don'k think you can add rows to sys.spatial_reference_system.

Comment: missread mssql to mysql, just like google does. see http://www.hackingsqlserver.com/2010/03/modifying-system-tables-in-sql-server.html i didn't try it but it there has to be way edit those tables and that page has howto

Comment: Also see : http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54820/add-new-srid-to-sql-server And it http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4e3b8a82-64e4-4f21-b96c-319e5eccd0e9/custom-wellknown-text-representation-of-spatial-reference-systems At end , if you use geometry type you can use nonexistend srid, it is not a problem inside db because there is no transformation tools and calculation use cartesian coordinates. With geography type it is problem.

Comment: I accepted this answer because there is currently no solution to add new SRS to MSSQL.